# json.net: serialise property of generic List

Tags: json, serialization

I have "Person" class and "NamedList" class derived from generic list:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class NamedList : List<Person>
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I added instance of person to instance of named list:

```
NamedList namedList = new NamedList();
namedList.Name = "Persons";

Person person = new Person();
person.FullName = "James Bond";

namedList.Add(person);
```

I serialized named list using JSON.Net library:

```
string serializedNamedList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(namedList, Formatting.Indented);
```

Present result of serialization is:

```
[
  {
    "FullName": "James Bond"
  }
]
```

but I'd like to get the name of list serialized a s well, like this:

```
{
    "Name": "Persons"
    [
        {
            "FullName": "James Bond"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve it?
Thank you

Comment: The exact way you propose is not doable because it violates json syntax

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of deriving `NamedList` from `List<Person>`, defined the `List<Person>` as a member variable of the `NamedList` class, and declare a method `add(Person p)` in the `NamedList` class that appends to the internal list.